# how to add pound(#) symbol in pandas 'to_csv' header?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas DataFrame` and I would like to save the ***DataFrame in a tab separated file format with pound(#)*** symbol at the beginning of the header.

Here is my demo code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

file_name = 'test.tsv'

df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', index=False)
```

The above code create a dataframe and save it in a tab separated value format. that looks like:

```
a  b  c
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

But how I can add add pound symbol with the header while saving the DataFrame. 
I want the output to be like bellow:

```
#a  b  c
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

Hope I am clear with the question and thanks in advance for the help.

Note: I would like to keep the DataFrame header definition same

Answer (score 2):

Using your code, just modify the `a` column to be `#a` like below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['#a', 'b', 'c'])

file_name = 'test.tsv'

df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', index=False)
```

## Edit

If you don't want to adjust the starting dataframe, use `.rename` before sending to csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

file_name = 'test.tsv'

df.rename(columns={
    'a' : '#a'
}).to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `header` argument to create aliases for the columns.

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', index=False,
          header=[f'#{x}' if x == df.columns[0] else x for x in df.columns])

#a  b   c
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

Here's another way to get your column aliases:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
header = [''.join(x) for x in zip_longest('#', df.columns, fillvalue='')]
#['#a', 'b', 'c']
```